# Notepad++ with Local and FTP synchronizer. [?]

Tags: ftp, notepad++

Does the Notepad++ have Local and FTP synchronizer by any plugin?? because I develop websites using PHP and notepad++ has all the features I like and its really lightweight but I had to switch to Netbeans because I use a web hosting but I always like to save the code in my computer too. and netbeans can do that, even anything you insert locally in the folder it automatically adds the folder and the files in the FTP server which is great. but if the notepad++ has the feature to at least update the files that we are saving in notepad++ in both local and ftp server I would be so glad, I search that for a long time, but I can't use netbeans anymore I lose way too much time, netbeans is really heavy!

Thanks!

Comment: If you find yourself developing on a Linux+KDE system, you can use Kate and the fish:// protocol to do the same thing. Open your file browser, enter in `fish://user@ip.add.re.ss/`, enter password, and right-click -> open file in Kate. Everything is synced automatically when you save. This question helped me with a Windows solution of the same nature, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> NppFTP: a plugin that allows FTP,
>   FTPS, FTPES and SFTP communications.
>   Very useful for web development.
>   Author: harrybharry
>   Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/

Install it from **Plugin Manager**
[image: Install it from Plugin Manager]

These are NppFTP plugin panel and toolbar button
[image: These are NppFTP plugin panel and toolbar button]

Open **profile settings** dialog
[image: Open profile settings dialog]

Then configure profiles
[image: Then configure profiles]

Comment: I'm aware of this one, the thing I want is to make the local and ftp syncronization like the Netbeans does. do you have some solution for that in Notepad++?? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP is asking. nppFTP uploads, sure, but you still have to keep selecting the right folder on the remote folder list, which can be taxing after a while, especially when you're using a framework like CodeIgniter where you're modifying files in different folders all the time, like controller, model, view, and js and css folders.

Comment: Well, @TARKUS, this question was asked 6 years ago, and my answer was accepted by OP, so I suppose it answered somehow the question by then.

Comment: The question was "Does the Notepad++ have Local and FTP synchronizer by any plugin??" I don't see that in the present answer is all I'm saying. Sometimes OPs will check an answer as correct, because at the time there is no better answer, not because it's the right answer. There seems to have been an FTP_synchronize plugin at some point (which appears to be your answer, below, and probably more correct than this answer), but it doesn't show up in my plugins list. I guess double-clicking the remote file, then CTRL-S is the best we can hope for. Better yet, see @ryan-wheale's answer, below.

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to post this here for anybody looking for the same solution I was looking for... (and I think helps answer this question more thoroughly).

I keep an exact replica of my public_html directory on my local machine.  I wanted to be able to double click a file on the remote server and live edit so that I had a mirrored copy on my local machine.  Note: if you are looking for functionality similar to Dreamweaver's site manager... there is a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3025586&group_id=321962&atid=1353003) for that.  This solution only allows your local files to get updated when you edit a remote file.

So here goes the basic connection settings (pretty standard):

```
h: some.ftphost.com
u: some_ftp_user
p: a_very_secure_password
d: /public_html
```

Then, here is where the magic comes in.  Under the "cache" tab for the ftp profile,  add the following:

```
Local path: E:\Path\to\your\local\server\public_html
External path: /public_html
```

The external path should be the same as the "initial directory" in your connection settings.  Hope this makes sense.  Please ask questions if you have any.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: External Path being same as Initial Directory was the missing link for so long. Thanks!

Comment: This is without a doubt the best and the right answer! In NPP make sure you hit save/edit on the cache section too, I changed it and forgot to hit edit to save.

Answer (score 3):

Then what you need is rather [FTP_synchronize](http://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/)

> double-clicking file will open it for
>   editing and saving file (in usual way)
>   will update it on server .

Comment: Cool. The real question is: Can we save both copies local and ftp with the usual ctrl+s command? Im searching for that feature. Im testing bot Notepad++ and SublimeText because that. (Use IDE is not a must, they are not lightweight and doesn't not do magic into the code :) Thanks

Comment: If you are connected to the server and editing a file you downloaded through NppFTP then pressing CTRL+S will save the file locally (in the \NppFTP\Cache\ folder) and upload the file to the server at the same time. Because it is so seamless, some people think you actually edit the file on the server through Npp, but that is not the case. 

(This is a couple years after the fact, but put here in case someone comes later looking for answers)

Answer (score 2):

I actually prefer the way that Notepad++ works with FTP compared to Netbeans. Notepad++ always treats the remote file as the master copy. So when you open it, it first downloads it and stores it in the local cache. Netbeans however always opens the local copy first - you have to explicitly synchronise with the external server to pull down the files from the server. If you're working with other developers - its much better to use the server copy so that you pull down any changes by other developers.

If you want the synchronisation try these steps:

1. In Notepad++ | NppFTP | Global Settings | Set the Global cache to be `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\%USERNAME%@%HOSTNAME%` which works for IIS or change the directory to your webserver root directory
2. You will have to make sure Notepad++ has permissions to create directories in your server root
3. Download one file from the server using NppFTP so that you can see what the directory struction looks like you can probably put just `%HOSTNAME%` e.g. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.com`
4. Then use [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) to download all the files into that directory - you can also use Filezilla to check for synchronisation changes.
5. Then use NppFTP which will download the files into that structure.
6. You should then be able to access the files through localhost/domain.com
7. If you're the only one working on the project that should then be enough, but if there are others, or if you make changes elsewhere you can use Filezilla to check the file timestamps to synchronise.

Answer (score 0):

The default install for Notepad++ has a Plugin called NppFTP on the Plugins menu.  I don't know how feature-full it is, however.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get NppFTP
2. Connect to ftp.xxxx.com
3. Double click file to open
4. Edit changes
5. Save with automatic upload