# Can Notepad++ automatically upload local files to the server when I save?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I use Notepad++ with its NppFTP plugin. I am required to keep local copies up to date, so I edit the local files then upload them to the server. I'm wondering if there is a way for Notepad++ to automatically upload the file to the server as soon as I save it, without me having to press another button.

I'm open to using other FTP programs but I would rather stick with Notepad++ as the text editor

Comment: So you actually want to save the file in two locations, both local and remote?

Comment: I think Notepad++ cannot do this, although you can write macros and/or plugins that might. But I think it's easier to find a tool that automatically syncs local files with files on your server. There are various tools that can do this, like AutoSync. http://download.cnet.com/AutoSync/3000-2160_4-10571674.html Not sure if it's good, it's just a random tool I found.

Comment: I do know that Netbeans allows creating projects, and I think they have the option to copy files to a local folder, and copy it back to the remote server on save. But I haven't used this feature either, so I don't know the ins and outs.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks! If it can be done with macros and or plugins, then what kind of plugins or macros could I use?

Comment: @GolezTrol, As a long time NetBeans user, NetBeans definitely has this ability. I am trying to break into Notepad++ because it is so much less of a resource hog, and frankly, NetBeans seems to cause problems on my development machine. I really want the project sync feature of NetBeans in Notepad++, where I use a shortcut key combo, and it uploads the current file in focus to the correct folder on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this solely with Notepad++, I've gotten a similar workflow using Filezilla as well.

I set Notepad++ as my default text editor (Edit -> Settings -> File Editing -> Use Custom Editor) in Filezilla.

I can right-click on a local file (in Filezilla) and press "edit". Whenever I save the file in Notepad++, Filezilla detects the difference and prompts me to upload the file.

Will reply back to this post once I can get this process to be completely automatic.

Comment: Just wait, OP will deliver.

Comment: I forgot about this question, and I don't use Notepad++ anymore.. This is the closest solution that I've ever gotten so I will mark it as answered

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657233/2480481 - Process is similar than the proposed using Filezilla, but directly from Notepad++ plugin.

Comment: The @Gabriel Ryan Nahmias was better than this.

Comment: yeah, but now you have to use two programs.

Comment: This is exactly what I used to do BUT this is the problem I'm trying to solve - I don't want to have to alt-tab and click "ok" to upload - I just want it to upload... That's why @erm3nda has the best solution (below) to this dilemma

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is *slightly dated*, but I would just like to put out there to alleviate future confusion for anyone who tries to find an answer to this question that as far as I know, **NppFTP *currently does this by default***.  There is a window beneath the main file view area that informs you of current FTP operations.  Dreamweaver has started crapping out on me regularly so I had to find an equally powerful solution; it seems like Notepad++ just might be that!

Comment: I just checked this, and this isn't quite the functionality I need, as it only auto-uploads if you're editing the remote copy - not the local copy.

Comment: There's no much info about that on the net. Also, cache name on a pair of syncronized folders is not too much suggestive, because my localfolder cannot be called cache. Is MY project core.

Thanks for the advise. Was looking for something that already had.

Answer (score 5):

Researching about same problem , i found from the Notepad++ Plugin Manager **NppNetNote plugin**. It allow you to edit both files at time (Local and remote) wich is like edit local and publish.

**Edit:** I'm sorry. Mistake. Now that plugin is called NppDocShare, and acts as server/client for a live document. You can edit a file from two locations (Notepad++ executions) at twice, but cannot edit two files nor emulates the autoupload.

**I'd try the @Gabriel Ryan Nahmias and he's just RIGHT**. The NppFTP plugin does that you wanna, but is a little tricky (obvious when you do) to configure.

By default, the program uses a variable path (Global cache: `%CONFIGDIR%\Cache\%USERNAME%@%HOSTNAME%`) to store the local copy that is uploaded at save. **You need to create a pair folder when create a ftp CONNECTION PROFILE** to say to NppFTP plugin how you wanna threat the file/connection. Otherwise, the ftp file goes to global.

Once the profile is created, i.e; `C:\myfolder\` vs `/` (`/` is relative to ftp) any file Edited or Created will be created/autouploaded to FTP at save. Also, you can open the FTP file, and it will be threated as the local one. Untill you save that, the real local file is not overwritten. If you dont like the file from FTP, simply close file and open from the local folder. So, you can chose which document wanna edit at start :)

Works Like Magic. Now im in love with Notepad++ :)

Extra: The subfolder creation is not magic. This only works from FTP to Local. You can edit a file from FTP subfolder and the folder plus file will be reproduced into local. No way to create from Local to FTP. You must create the ftp subfolder by hand :X (Unexpected)

You can manage files by two ways. Creating a profile per folder/proyect or create multiple local cache directories to a single profile. BUT, only the first one will be available (You will reorder it on each use). No magic here :( and it's more easy to create profiles and choose from the droplist at connect.

Anyway, i think the NppFTP is doing the things very well.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'll check it out soon and update the Best Answer when I've tried it.

Comment: Legend.  I'd tried everything, even NPPFtp and didn't do what I needed... until I read this and saw the "create a pair folder" - this has made me happy today!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved updating the NppFTP plugin to the latest stable version.

Cheers!