# How to automatically FTP files that I am editing

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to figure out how to autoftp with Filezilla.  Are there any other programs that do this right off the bat?

Comment: Are you trying to create a FTP mount?  What OS?

Comment: Do you want to copy files from FileZilla to a server on a scheduled basis? Or from the server to FileZilla? Or do you want to just do it once e.g. on start up? What platform would you be running this on (Windows, Mac etc)?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: not sure ftp mount is, but I'm just trying to have filezilla automatically upload files that I'm editing, and when saving the files, filezilla just auto uploads them. im in windows 7

Comment: Write a script/program that scans your source directory(s) every x minutes and use an FTP library to upload when changes are detected. I'd be surprised if something like this doesn't already exist, and according to the answer below Notepad++ has this functionality.

Comment: to flesh out the question a little more as to why this will _probably_ not change: the filezilla admin proposes a two step syncing issue that is dangerously capable of corrupting your data with an autosync feature in pure FTP programs. There are also workarounds in **[the same filezilla thread post](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=14672)**

Comment: Filezilla now (2019) does provide a feature for auto-ftp-ing a file when it is changed.  If you right-click the local file, then select "Edit", Filezilla will automatically prompt to FTP the file from then on until you select the "stop editing" checkbox in the dialogue.  I just switch to the FileZilla window then press "Y" to proceed without having to use the mouse.  The WinSCP solution given in answers is probably the best option though.

Comment: I should have known this WinSCP feature 10 years ago, I had saved 100000 clicks on "Confirm override" that I needed to do in Filezilla. Ouch ... https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by "autoftp" you mean "update the file on the server whenever I save it" and you're working with code, then I'd recommend the wonderful [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: I'd like to know this also. I see that NPP has an FTP plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) but I can't find anything about automatically uploading on save. That would be really useful to me.

Comment: In the NP++ toolbar, there should be an icon of a folder with a chain on the bottom left.  That's the FTP

Comment: NppFTP will in fact do this. And HOW to do it is detailed in this guy's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908430/2063246

Answer (score 42):

I use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for some of its amazing benefits. I connect to my FTP server with WinSCP and let it monitor my local folder `/website/public_html`.

Any changes I make in my local folder automatically get uploaded to my FTP server by WinSCP. The feature is called *Keep remote directory up to date*:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date

As for SCSS, I also use it:
I have a script that opens a console window to watch my `/website/scss` files and compiles them to `/website/public_html/styles/`. WinSCP sees the CSS file has changed (or is new) and automatically uploads it.

Notice: The only downside is you cannot reach your `error_log` as that is automatically generated on the server by PHP. To do this you can easily instantiate another WinSCP to connect to your website. Now you have 1 WinSCP monitoring your local folder and 1 WinSCP  where you can access your site map.

Comment: So with WinSCP why do people even use FileZilla anymore?

Comment: How come it detected the change but not upload everytime?

Comment: Though note that you can open remote files in WinSCP internal editor or any external editor of your choice directly from the file panel. The file is than automatically uploaded whenever saved. This way, the problem never occurs, even with old FTP server. See [Editing/Opening Files](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_edit) and [Internal Text Editor](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editor).

Comment: WinSCP really good tools. I use it on Windows environment. Whenever you hit save, then it automatically uploaded to server. It is reduces workload. But unfortunate, the mac version is unavailable. Hopefully winscp also support for Mac environment

Answer (score 7):

Notepad++ certainly is wonderful for this particular function and it even saves a cache of the whatever has been accessed and modified from the remote server.

The downside however (for me) is that Notepad++ will not auto-upload preprocessed CSS files like .scss or .less.  I tried actually opening the resulting .css files in Notepad++ to mimic the act of editing them, but that still puts an extra step in the process. I have to click over to the tabs and manually save them (after the 'your file as changed prompt').

Currently, after I make changes, I click over to FZ and upload the files manually.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I came here looking for an answer to... anyone have an easier way to do this yet?

Comment: Since this comment, I have been using WinSCP which allows a user to select files and folders to "watch" for changes.  After .SCSS compresses and the modify date changes, WinSCP uploads to the remote server. http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full#synchronization_mode

Comment: Just got it, tested it, STOKED!!

Comment: If you're using N++, I believe crtl-shift-a is "save-all" - might save you the time of saving each.

Comment: I was waiting for Years for this Feature in FileZilla. Since I read about the Topic and the "problematic" about it -  from then i used WinSCP.  Better Choise !!

Answer (score 7):

This response is late, but hopefully it will be helpful to those looking to get past Filezilla's "do you want to overwrite" prompt every time a file being edited locally is saved. Unfortunately, the Filezilla developers are staunchly opposed to making this behavior optional. It is a problem for many, especially when working with limited desktop space, since every time the prompt appears, one must expose the hidden filezilla window just to click okay.

Anyway, the answer is WinSCP. It is also free and is so similar to filezilla that I needed no learning to use it immediately.

Cheers!

Comment: `Always perform this action for this file` ` --- during this session` would be a pair of nice features.

Comment: I use the options 'Overwrite if different size or source newer', 'Always use this action', 'Apply only to uploads' and then I can just upload the entire directory tree and FileZilla takes care of finding what is changed and only uploads that.

Comment: This reply is correct as of 2023, unfortunately, - here are the links / sources confirming the filezilla devs unreasonable and Stubborn opposition to auto updating *without a prompt at each file update*.  Because of this i have moved to WinSCP as well :(   [filezilla forums post #1 - from 2023](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=40005) /  [filezilla forums post #2 - from 2020](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=20445)  - there are several more examples over there also.. :(

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way to do that with **NetBeans IDE**, there is an option to upload files with **FTP** or **SFTP** on save, manually or on Run

---

1. Right click on your project and click **Properties**
2. Click the second category **run configuration**
3. Run As: Choose **Remote Website (FTP,SFTP)**
4. Project Url: put your website **live link** eg www.example.com
5. Upload files: Choose **On Save**
6. **Remote Connection** > Manage > Add > Connection name (put one) > FTP

---

Now add your ftp details. **Make sure your  Initial directory path is correct**, (your website path) so you will not accidentally replace any files from other website in the file manager

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there no option on filezilla can auto agree upload when file has been changed.

Mobaxtern can do that. You can choose "always upload" when file has been changed.

You can edit the file with any editor, whenever you save, it will upload.

Answer (score -1):

I like to use [WebDrive](https://southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/) ($40) which mounts a remote server (S)FTP/SSH/Cloud to a local drive (eg. X: on Windows). You can then just do everything to drive X: as if it's a local drive and WebDrive automatically uploads the changes to the remote server.