# How to deploy my project to localhost?

Tags: deployment, ftp, localhost, publish

I'm working on a website and right now I am using FileZilla to make changes to it. Every time I make a change, I have to re-upload the file to the website through FTP and then wait for it to update online. I want to just deploy my project to localhost so I can get instant results and then just upload the whole project when it's finished. How do I do this? All I have is a set of directories with the files in them.

Comment: You need to set up a web-server locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to use a web/application server such as IIS/Apache.
For PHP projects go for WampServer/XAMPP.Easy to setup and works very well.

Answer (score 1):

(maybe too obvious)
If you are working only static content based on html/css/js you can just edit and view changes directly by opening the local file in your browser and refresh each time.
Furthermore for css and html you can edit your code "live", directly into browser and see changes immidiately.

Another option is to edit files with an editor that supports ftp like notepad++, you can connect via ftp, open and edit files directly from server (like php,html,css,js) because once you save the editor will automatically upload your changes.
Heres a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656779/notepad-with-local-and-ftp-synchronizer) about notepad++ and ftp plugin.

Localserver
If you work with php (and even only with html/css) the best choise is to run a local server that rappresents a real environment in which your code will run. As said by others XAMPP is a good choise for begginers because of simple installation and management.
[XAMPP download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)
[XAMPP tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server)
Once installed put your folder inside C:/xampp/htdocs/yourCodeFolder
Run the xampp control panel and start the Apache server.
Finally navigate with your browser to: `http://localhost/yourCodeFolder/`

Comment: With notepad++ can you see your changes live (or at least a preview of what it will look like)? If so then notepad++ is exactly what I need.

Comment: So you are working only on visual content (css/html), right?
Notepad++ with the ftp plugin is just an editor that downloads the file from server, after you edit and save it will just upload the file back on server. Then you have to refresh the browser.

For live css editing you can use chrome with extensions like 
[livecsseditor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-css-editor/oelggcmknbjmhkpgjfhakedcfnkgbdpg)

[Here a demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlY1tVXCpd0)

Comment: I looked at notepadd++ and it looks good but unfortunately they do not support Mac.  :(