# Notepad ++ auto complete not working when coding on a server

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++, filezilla, code-editor

When I write code locally on my computer using notepad ++ (Just from my desktop, documents folder, etc.) the autocompletion works just fine.

However, when I open an HTML or PHP file from Filezilla the autocompletion no longer works.

Can anyone suggest how I may overcome this or is it something I just have to live with when working on a server?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656779/notepad-with-local-and-ftp-synchronizer check this

Comment: https://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/ plugin for notepad+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ with Local and FTP synchronizer. \[?\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656779/notepad-with-local-and-ftp-synchronizer)